# Front panel audio replacement

Tags: audio, front-panel

I have experienced some problems with my headphones and it turned out the front 3.5mm audio jack is defective..and it doesn't make a good contact. I can't replace the jack because it's built-in.

I am wondering if there are such things as "modular" Front panels **to be inserted into the available external 3.5" bay** and, of course, to support (natively, internal connector) Realtek **HD Audio**.

*(my case is Asus TA-K5, but I guess it doesn't make any difference)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the short answer is *yes*, though this turns into a shopping question if you go any further. However, since I already have the links up:

`3.5" bay front panel audio` is what I plugged into Google, and the results show a whole host of products, most within the $20-$30 range, which is about what I would expect to pay for something like this. [This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JK7FMW) and [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811996006) both explicitly state that they support the HD audio connector.

Comment: Right.  Usually the front panel connectors are fed from cables that plug into the motherboard.  If you're lucky, you can find a stock item that will plug in in place of your balky connector.  If a little less lucky you may have to splice some wires.